# Correct way to create a custom comparer for linq join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have some problems creating a custom comparer to be used in linq.join.
I'm not very expert in linq, so I probably misunderstood join function behavior.

This is my code. I want to perfor a simple join between those two lists:

```
List<MyObj> operand1Data = new List<MyObj>()
{
    new MyObj() { Var = "1var1", Year = 0 },
    new MyObj() { Var = "1var2", Year = 2018 },
};

List<MyObj> operand2Data = new List<MyObj>()
{
    new MyObj() { Var = "2var1", Year = 2018 },
    new MyObj() { Var = "2var2", Year = 2019 },
    new MyObj() { Var = "2var3", Year = 2020 },
};

var result= operand1Data.Join(operand2Data, x => x.Year, y => y.Year, (x, y) => x.Var + y.Var, new TestComparer()).ToList();
```

The problem is that I want 0 to match with every element in the other list, so I came up with this custom comparer:

```
public class TestComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    public bool Equals(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This does not work. The result only contains:

```
"1var12var3"
"1var22var1"
```

and what I expected was:

```
"1var12var1"
"1var12var2"
"1var12var3"
"1var22var1"
```

What am I missing? Can someone help me fixing this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tried your code and i guess that LINQ Join have a default filter that gets applied before the custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

With a log inside the `Equals(x,y)`, this is what i got:

> ```
> "Equality test x:2018 y:2019 = False"
> "Equality test x:2019 y:2020 = False"
> "Equality test x:2018 y:2020 = False"
> "Equality test x:2020 y:0 = True"
> "Equality test x:2020 y:2018 = False"
> "Equality test x:2019 y:2018 = False"
> "Equality test x:2018 y:2018 = True"
> ```

You see? Only one "zero" equality check.

So, my suggestion is to use the linq query-syntax with a cross join, then filter elements by `where` conditions:

```
var result = from o1 in operand1Data
             from o2 in operand2Data
             where o1.Year == 0 || o2.Year == 0 || o1.Year == o2.Year
             select o1.Var + o2.Var;
```

The result is exactly what you're looking for:

> ```
> "1var12var1"
> "1var12var2"
> "1var12var3"
> "1var22var1"
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ty for your help. Performing your same test, I came to the conclusion that the "join" operation creates an "equality map" between elements of the second list in order to reduce the number of test it has to perform with elements of the first list. This would explain the behavior: since 2020 is not equal to any other element in the second list and is equal to 0 in the first list, it assumes that  0 is not equal to other elements in the second list too. I could not find any documents about that, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion is not suitable for me: this is just a simple example to show my problem, but in reality "MyObj" is much more complex than this and I need to compare properties based on variable key selectors.
The solution I was thinking about is to split the operation in two part: a simple join and then a cross between the 0 elements with all others. The union of two operations should be the result I want.

Comment: Oh, if your only need is about using a variable key selector, then keep your `IEqualityComparer<T>` class and use it in the where clause: `where new TestComparer().Equals(o1, o2)`. Anyway there is a lot of ways to achive that, the single cross join operation seems more elegant for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should update function Equals and GetHashCode

```
Equals(MyObj? b1, MyObj? b2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(b1, b2))
        return true;

    if (b2 is null || b1 is null)
        return false;

    return b1.Year == 0 || b2.Year == 0 || b1.Year == b2.Year;
}
GetHashCode(MyObj obj) => obj.Year;
```